# What are the Vibhutis of Lord Shiva as told in Mahabharata?

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, shiva, history

Vibhuti means through which potency of Lord is expressed. Bhagvad Gita 10th chapter is itself named as Vibhuti Yoga and we find several descriptions about Vibhuti of Lord there like:

> आदित्यानामहं विष्णुर्ज्योतिषां रविरंशुमान् ।
>   मरीचिर्मरुतामस्मि नक्षत्राणामहं शशी ॥१०- २१॥
>  
>   Of the Adityas I am Vishnu, of lights I am the radiant sun, of the Maruts I am Marici, and among the stars I am the moon.
>   
>   वेदानां सामवेदोऽस्मि देवानामस्मि वासवः ।
>   इन्द्रियाणां मनश्चास्मि भूतानामस्मि चेतना ॥१०- २२॥
>  
>   Of the Vedas I am Samaveda, of devas I am Vaasava, of the Indriyas I am Mana, of the beings I am their consciousness.
>   
>   रुद्राणां शंकरश्चास्मि वित्तेशो यक्षरक्षसाम् ।
>   वसूनां पावकश्चास्मि मेरुः शिखरिणामहम् ॥१०- २३॥
>  
>   Of Rudras I'm Shankara, of Yaksha I'm Vittesha , of Vasus I'm Pavaka and of mountains I'm Meru.

And so on. As I discuss in my answer [here,](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11529/i-want-scripture-based-explanation-for-god-is-everywhere/15705#15705) Brahman is equated to be everything of this universe. Like SataRudriya states:

> Salutations to him who is chariot itself, maker of chariot, rider of chariot, charioteer, horses and lord of horses.

Likewise as I discuss [here,](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10584/how-does-the-names-and-events-reoccur-in-different-manvantara-or-kalpa-or-differ/15573#15573) Shiva Purana states:

> ब्रह्मादितृणपर्यन्तं यत्किञ्चिद्दृश्यते त्विह ।
>   तत्सर्वं शिव एवास्ति मिथ्या नानात्व कल्पना ।।
>  
>   Right from Brahma to the twig of leaf, ie . Everything in this Universe is Shiva himself. The concept of manifestation is not real.

So, Brahman is equated with everything of this Universe. But still for describing Brahman he can be described through his various Vibhutis which are present in this world. 

Various Vibhutis of Lord Shiva are stated itself in Yajurveda Sata Rudriya Hymn. But, **are there any instances in Mahabharata where Vibhutis of Lord Shiva is spoken?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, In [Chapter 14](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13a014.htm) of Anushashana Parva of Mahabharata various Vibhutis of Lord Shiva are told. Lord Krishna is narrating these verses to Yudhisthira (and others) which were previously told by Upamanyu while praising Mahadeva.

> त्वं नो गतिश्च श्रेष्ठस्च त्वमेव हृदयं तथा ।
>   त्वं ब्रह्मा सर्वदेवानां रुद्राणां निललोहित ।।
>  
>   You are the most superior path among Paths. You are heart of all. You are **Brahma** among all **Devas** and You are **Nilalohita** among **Rudra.**
>   
>   आत्मा च सर्वभूतानां सांख्ये पुरुष उच्यते ।
>   ऋषभस्त्वं पवित्राणां योगिनां निष्कल शिव।।
>  
>   You are all Pervading Atman. You are **Purush** of the **Sankhya.** You are **Rishabha** among **sacred things** and you are that whom yogis call Shiva.
>   
>   गृहस्थत्वत्वमाश्रमीणामीश्वराणां महेश्वर ।
>   कुबेरः सर्वयक्षाणां क्रतूनां विष्णुरुच्यते ।।
>  
>   You are **Grihastha ashrama** among the **ashramas.** You are **Maheswara** in the **Ishwara.** You are **Kubera** among **Yakshas** and You are **Vishnu** in the **Yajnas.**
>   
>   पर्वतानां भवान् मेरुर्नक्षत्राणां च चन्द्रमा ।
>   वसिष्ठस्त्त्वमृषिणां च ग्रहाणां सूर्य उच्यते ।।
>  
>   You are **Meru** among the **mountains.** You are **Chandrama** among the **Nakshtras.** You are **Vasistha** among the **Rishis** and **Surya** among the **planets.**
>   
>   आरण्यानां पशूनां च सिंहस्त्त्वं परमेश्वर ।
>   ग्राम्याणां गोवृषश्वासि भवाॅल्लोकप्रपूजित।।
>  
>   Parameshwara! You are **Lion** among the **animals which live in forest** and You are **Ox** among the **domestic animals** which is worshipped by the whole world.
>   
>   आदित्यानां भवान् विष्णुर्वसुनां चैव पावक ।
>   पक्षिणां चैनतेयस्त्वमनन्तो भुजगेषु च ।।
>  
>   You are **Vishnu** among the **Adityas.** You are **Pavaka** among **Vasus.** You are **Garuda** among **birds** and You are **Ananta** among the **snakes.**
>   
>   सामवेदश्च वेदानां यजुषां शतरुद्रियम् ।।
>   सनत्कुमारो योगीनां सांख्यानां कपिलो ह्यसी ।
>  
>   You are **Samaveda** among the **Vedas.** You are **SataRudriya**  inside **Yajurveda.** You are **Sanatkumara** among **Yogis** and You are **Kapila** among **Sankhyas.**
>   
>   शक्रोऽसि मरुतां देव पितृणां ह्व्यवाडसि ।
>   ब्रह्मलोकश्च लोकानां गतीनां मोक्ष उच्यसे ।।
>  
>   You are **Marut** among **Shakra.** You are **Devarata** among **Pitris.** You are **Brahma Loka** among **Lokas** and You are **Moksha** among the **attainments.**
>   
>   क्षीरोदः सागराणां च शैलानां हिमवान् गिरिः।
>   वर्णनां ब्रह्माणाश्चासि विप्राणां दीक्षितो द्विज ।।
>  
>   You are **Kshira Sagara** among **oceans.** You are **Himavan** among **ShailaGiri.** You are **Brahmana** among **Varnas** and You are **initiated Brahmana** among **Brahmanas.**
>   
>   आदिस्त्वमसि लोकानां संहर्ता काल एव च ।
>   यच्चान्यदपि लोके वै सर्वतेजोऽधिकंस्मृतम् ।।
>  
>   You are **origin** of this world and you are destroyer and **Kaala** of this world. **Whatever there is in this world with brilliancy, you are remembered by that.**

Comment: Nice one,im also planning to post Parama shiva's vibhutis from Puranas..

Comment: @Rickross Hmm..  that's good idea... post it soon... btw you may already know... Shiva Purana Vayaviya Samhita chapter 4 contains Vibhuti of Shiva Shakti..

Comment: @Uday Krishna The Brahman which is used in  question is ब्रह्म । so it can't be written in answer. The "Brahmanas" represent two thing one Varna and another commentary on Samhitas of Vedas like "Satapatha Brahmana" Both have same spelling.. and written as "ब्राह्मण"।..... and "Brahmin" is a recent word (I think"...