# Panentheism & Hinduism

Tags: brahman

Aum - Is the concept of Brahman, in the Philosophy of Hinduism, comparable with the Ideology of Panentheism? (the belief or doctrine that God is greater than the universe and includes and interpenetrates it.)

From my research it seems to match, however I'm not certain if Brahman is separate from the universe, as well as a part of the Universe, or rather is Brahman the Universe, and nothing else? (Pantheism)

[image: Panentheism]

Comment: There are different intrepretations of scriptures. Dvaita philosophy helds that Universe is seperate from Brahman... whereas Advaita philosophy helds that Universe itself is also Brahman.. for eg: [here.](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11529/i-want-scripture-based-explanation-for-god-is-everywhere/15705#15705)

Comment: the Western theological concept of pantheism most closely compares to the vedanta philosophy of vishishtadvaita. It is not comparable to the advaita philosophy, nor is it comparable to the dvaita philosophy. Your diagram of Theism compares to the dvaita philosophy. A comparable Western concept of advaita is found in the SIx Enneads of Plotinus. I use the terms compares/comparable in all three instances as they are not completely the same between the Eastern traditions and the Western traditions.

Comment: I don't think panentheism can be compared to Advaita. The universe, a projection of Brahman, is ultimately unreal while panentheism considers the universe as real.

Comment: Figure one does not full-fill the definition of Aum which is onmipresent.

Comment: universe is GOD when looked differently and vice versa.universe is at once a process and statitic

Comment: in fact this is the basis of ethics ,like why you should not hurt or steel as God is the transedental reality pervading all individuals

Answer (score 2):

According to Upanishads, all this creation emerges from Brahman, lives in the Brahman and dissolves in the Brahman.

Chhaqndogya Upanishad:

> सर्वं खल्विदं ब्रह्म तज्जलानिति शान्त उपासीत ..... ॥ ३.१४.१॥
>
> III-xiv-1: **Verily, all this universe is Brahman. From Him do all things originate, into Him do they dissolve and by Him are they sustained.** On Him should one meditate in tranquility.....

Taittariya Upanishad:

> ..... यतो वा इमानि भूतानि जायन्ते । येन जातानि जीवन्ति ।
>   यत्प्रयन्त्यभिसंविशन्ति । तद्विजिज्ञासस्व । तद्ब्रह्मेति ।
>   स तपोऽतप्यत । स तपस्तप्त्वा ॥ १॥
>
> III-i-1: ..... "Crave to know **that from which all these beings take birth, that by which they live after being born, that towards which they move and into which they merge.** That is Brahman". He practiced concentration. He, having practiced concentration.

You may also refer BG 7.4 to 7.7 and Mundaka Upanishad 1.1.7

Though I don't know much about Pantheism however it looks that according to Pantheism, *god and universe are identical* - that philosophy/concept seems in agreement but *actually Brahman in **not** conditioned or limited* to world/universe only. Brahman is beyond his creation. See the following verses from [Srimad Bhagavad Gita](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?etgb=1&choose=1&&language=dv&field_chapter_value=9&field_nsutra_value=4):

> 9.4 This whole world is prevaded by Me in My unmanifest form. All beings exist in Me, but I am not contained in them!
>   9.5 Nor do the beings dwell in Me. Behod My divine Yoga! I am the sustainer and originator of beings, but My Self is not contained in the beings