# How do Hindu kids see with their eyes closed?

Tags: yoga, meditation

There are plenty of videos on the Internet which show such talents of Hindu children. Example:

- [Samyak Jain Super Wonder Kid who can read with closed eyes](https://youtu.be/zJ4jqMZR5Os)
- [Human X-Ray machine: Unbelievable Eye sight](https://youtu.be/i3SX_1HEGnw)
- [Girl demonstrates Cool SuperPower (Third Eye)](https://youtu.be/ZtLkzg8bFgA)
- [Can you read blindfolded? This 8-year-old can](http://www.hindustantimes.com/delhi/can-you-read-blindfolded-this-8-year-old-can/story-q8vha4Ie7xbcSSjjyE0ZmM.html)

How it is possible for these blindfolded kids to read books and do everything?

Is it a yoga technique or a God-gifted power?

Comment: Is t dermo optical perception(DOP)? What does science say about it?

Comment: Art of Living teaches a similar thing to teenagers. They run some kind of intuition program and teach kids to see stuff with vision completely blocked. There are videos on this as well. But unfortunately, I don't know how this is even possible for kids.

Comment: Yes! that's what I meant to ask

Answer (score 5):

I'm not really sure if all those videos are true, but it's possible to attain Siddhis (or some occult powers) through birth as mentioned in **Sutra 1, Adhyaya 4 of Patanjali Yoga Sutras**.

> जन्मओषधिमन्त्रतपस्समाधिजाः सिद्धयः ॥१॥ 
>   janma-oṣadhi-mantra-tapas-samādhi-jāḥ siddhayaḥ ॥1॥
>
> The Siddhis (powers) are attained by birth, chemical means, power of
>   words, mortification or concentration.

**Swami Vivekananda commentary**:

> Sometimes a man is born with the Siddhis, powers, of course from the
>   exercise of powers he had in his previous birth. In this birth he is
>   born, as it were, to enjoy the fruits of them. It is said of Kapila,
>   the great father of the Sankhya Philosophy, that he was a born Siddha,
>   which means, literally, a man who has attained to success.

**Commentary of Vyasa**: (translated by Ganganatha Jha)

> Com :— **The Power due to birth is brought about by corporeal
>   change**, " By herbs: " e.g, the medicinal preparations in the house
>   of the Asaras (i.e, Påtåla) " By incantations." Such as the
>   acquirement of " Molecularity " (Animå ),  "By austerities" the 
>   capability of approaching the sky, accomplishment of desire, e.g,
>   being capable of attaining any desirable form, the yogi moves about
>   here, there and  everywhere, in accordance with his own unimpeded
>   will, The  Powers due to Meditation have already been described.
>
> **Notes** :—( 1 ) "*Corporeal change*' - Sometimes the actions of the yogi  in his earthly life are developed to such on extent that he is
>   directly  born among the gods, with a celestial body, and as such
>   molecularity  ind the rest come to him naturally,

These occult powers in those kids might be due to their past birth vasanas.

Answer (score 3):

Rishi's answer is correct.A Yogi can see that is not seen by eyes when he obtains mastery over the [Manipura Chakra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manipura). This is one of the many siddhis that Yoga has to offer.

From [Siva Samhita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiva_Samhita) ,Chapter 5 :

> 81- **When the Yogi contemplates on the Manipur lotus,** he gets the power of
>   patala siddhi,-the giver of constant happiness.He becomes lord of
>   desires ,destroys sorrows and diseases,cheats death,and can enter body
>   of others(parakaya pravessha)
>
> [image]
>
> 82-He can make gold,etc,see the adepts(clairvoyantly),discover medicines
>   for diseases,**and see hidden treasures.**

Now, since he can see hidden treasures means that he does not need external eyes to see things.It's then when he can  see things even with his eyes closed.

The important thing to note here is that Manipura is associated with fire element.And fire is associated with form(rupa) just like say prithvi(Muladhara is the related Chakra) is associated with the sense of smell.And forms appear to us with the help of vision.

So,its natural that a Yogi obtains a vision-related siddhi by mastering the Manipura(fire) within him.

EDIT-I missed that you are actually asking about children.Only two possible explanations are there IMO-either they have learned  Yoga to do so Or they are carrying forward their powers which they have obtained in their previous births.

Comment: This is true for Yogis who activated Chakras. But how can we explain in case of 8 year old?

Comment: @The Destroyer Who's that 8 year old?May be he is carrying forward his powers from previous births..

Comment: OP's question is about this peculiar behavior of some children. But this is also a possible reason for their skills.

Comment: Ok as usual i missed reading the children part ;(..anyways let the Op decide..BTw whats the problem with kids mastering Yoga?

Comment: No Problem but most of them acquired innately those skills. Also, i never heard of people born with activated Chakras. Sri Krishna may be an exception but He is Avatar.  Few sages showed such skills from birth but not sure whether their chakras were activated innately.

Comment: @TheDestroyer God is omni present, So he will not and can not take avatars, Krishna was indeed a very high self realized soul, these souls can take birth with out mothers Womb as they have complete access to 5 elements, So IMO Krishna could be self realized yogi, but this too is not sure that he attained moksha or not, as vedas says one who has attained moksha will only come back after millions of bharama ratri.

Comment: @Rishi Brahman can come at his won will. Realized souls won't have powers of creation, Preservation and destruction. Brahman (as Krishna) said Gita to Arjuna.  In BG 4.8, he says "sambhavami yuge yuge".

Comment: @TheDestroyer **4.8 For the protection of the good, for the destruction of the wicked and for the establishment of righteousness, I am born in every age.**, This does not prove he is omnipresent bharaman himself, you are right they do not have powers of creation, but I said they can create a body for them-self only

**4.9 He who thus know, in their true light, My divine birth and action, having abandoned the body, is not born again, he comes to Me, O Arjuna.** This is next shaloka which says is not born again

Comment: @Rishi Many vedic verses say about omnipresence of Brahman.  See [I want scripture-based explanation for “God is Everywhere”](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11529/i-want-scripture-based-explanation-for-god-is-everywhere)

Comment: @Rishi Come to https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38640/vedanta-and-philosophy for discussions.

Comment: @TheDestroyer I will have to research **Aitreya Upanishad [2.6.1]**

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to see with eyes closed I have seen people who are literally blind and **will tell you the color of the cloth by touching it** and we all have seen it on television as well.

so what is the catch, it is just that this body is way more complicated machine, **it is all about perception**.

If today is about to rain there will be certain changes in our bodies, if you can observe them, **you can always tell by observing your body that it is going to rain today**.

There are people who will tell everything about you after just seing a picture of you, it is all that they can access certain dimension through this physical body, which indeed sounds phenomenal.

**In Hinduism these are called Siddhis.**

**But yogi should not go after Siddhis, as your spiritual growth will stop.**

We always carry a thing called "Sanskar" from past lives, So if you have practiced good things it will become sankar and will go in next life as well.

So the essence is that we should start listening to our body, soon you will be able to see what this body is asking for.