# Good and Evil and Reincarnation

Tags: rebirth

I'm a day new to Hinduism.  Does Hinduism teach that your God is the creator of good and evil?  The Bible infers this, that God is working everything according to his will.

I have a suspicion that Hinduism teaches something similar, though probably describes it in a very different way.

If we are controlled by Fate, then why is there reincarnation?  Is that just the way your God has decided to orchestrate it all?

EDIT:. Another way of asking, in Hinduism there isn't an eternal "battle" of good vs. evil, is there?

Comment: [This](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15705/3500)  might be helpful.

Comment: no there is no eternal battle. There is only ignorance, no absolute evil. All will succeed in reaching God in Hinduism. There is no devil, no eternal hell. Because of past tendencies, some take longer than others, but all make it to God.