# What's the proof that God exists?

Tags: gods, belief

I haven't seen or experienced him. So how do I say God exists? If you are giving example of oxygen or air, I would say I can at least feel it. How can you say God exists even thought you can't of feel it? Science doesn't approve existence of God. What's the proof that God exists?
Edit: my question is how do you prove his existence

Comment: I have never tasted sugar. Can you prove to me that sugar tastes sweet ? But one condition, you should not force me to eat sugar. You can use any other method to prove to me that sugar tastes sweet. Can you do it ?

Comment: At least I can taste sugar. You can't experience God

Comment: Look at Vedanta Sutra 1.1.3 and 2.1.27

Comment: @PratikCJoshi because Sugar is material or physical entity. Brahman (or ultimate reality) is beyond mind or senses. So, you can't feel that with senses or other instruments (which are again but senses).

Comment: In order to realise the taste of sugar, you have no other option to taste it by yourself. Similarly in order to attain Atma Jnana and Brahma Jnana you have to rely on scriptures.

Comment: You said you can feel the air, any kind of knowledge which can be known through five senses and feelings like sad, love, etc is called as pratyaksha Pramana. You can feel the air through skin, so it is a Pratyaksha pramana.

Comment: Second principle Pramana is Anumana. Assumption, doubting  and speculation of your mind based upon the Pratyaksha Pramana is called Anumana. For example, you are looking at smoke which is coming out beyond the tall building. Now you are using your mind and thinking that something is burning beyond the tall building, that's why smoke is coming. See, you are using  your mind and speculate that something is burning, that's why smoke is coming (there is no smoke without fire).

Comment: For things which you perceived directly, there is no need to use the mind and speculate. If you perceived the fire directly, there is no need for speculation. But if you perceive only smoke, but not fire, you need to speculate like I said before, something is burning beyond the tall building or something burnt long ago beyond the tall building (sometimes smoke will come even after the fire was extinguished)

Comment: The third Pramana is Sabda Pramana(knowledge we gain from Vedas and other scriptures learnt from a Guru coming form a bona-fide sampradaya). Sabda Pramana deals with Atman and Brahman. Atman and Brahman can be known neither through Pratyaksha nor through Anumana. Just like you are using mind to speculate for things which cannot be perceived by five senses, similarly for things which cannot be perceived by neither through Pratyaksha nor through Anumana, you have to rely on scriptures (Sabda Pramana) only.

Comment: @NaveenKick You could convert your comments into an answer, it will be more helpful that way.

Comment: @PratikCJoshi, you are only able to taste sugar because someone paid for it and gave it to you, most likely your parents, who happen to love you. similarly, if you are fortunate enough to get a sadh-acharya who can do the same for you, you can taste God.

Answer (score 11):

**my question is how do you prove his existence?**

Swami krishnananda logically proves (mostly from Advaitic perspective) God/Brahman exists in his book [**Lessons on the Upanishads**](https://www.swami-krishnananda.org/upanishad/upan_01.html).

Swamiji proves there is something which doesn't change in everything and says that is nothing but Brahman (ultimate Reality).

> We begin to feel there must be something above this world. This was
>   what the great poets and the sages of the Vedas felt. Everything seems
>   to be transitory, moving, and in a state of flux. There is change in
>   nature, change in human history, change in our own mental and
>   biological constitution, change in even the solar system, the
>   astronomical setup of things. Everything is changing. The perception
>   of change is something very important for us to consider. How do we
>   know that things are changing, that things are moving or are
>   transitory? There is a logical peculiarity, a significance and a
>   subtlety at the back of this ability on our part to perceive change
>   and transition in things. A thing that changes cannot perceive change
>   by itself. **Change cannot know change. Only that which does not
>   change can know that there is change.**
>
> This is a very important point at the rock bottom of our thinking that
>   we have to recognise. If everything is changing, who is it that is
>   telling us that everything is changing? Are we also changing with the
>   things that change? If that is the case, how do we come to know that
>   all things are changing? Logical analysis of this peculiar analytical
>   circumstance tells us that there is something in us which does not
>   change; otherwise, we would not know that things are changing.
>
> Now, if oneself – this person or that person – seems to be obliged to
>   recognise something in one's own self that does not seem to be
>   changing because one perceives change in general, we also have to be
>   charitable enough to accept that everyone in the world has this
>   something which does not change. **I have something in me which does not
>   change, and you also have something in you that does not change. If
>   this is the case, it seems to be everywhere.** It does not mean that
>   this unchanging so-called thing is only in one person, as all persons
>   have an equal prerogative to conclude that something unchanging seems
>   to be there, speaking in a language which is not subject to connection
>   with changeable objects.
>
> The Veda Samhitas to which I have made reference – which are the
>   outpourings of spiritual seekers, sages and masters of advanced
>   religious thought and spiritual perfection – felt the presence
>   everywhere of something that does not change. All things seem to be
>   embedded with something that cannot change. This is due to a logical
>   conclusion to which we are led – namely, that the perception of change
>   would not be possible if everything, including oneself, including even
>   the perceiver of change, also changes. Therefore, transitoriness
>   implies a non-transitory background of things.
>
> The whole universe of perception, the entire creation, may be said to
>   be involved basically, at the root, in something which cannot be said
>   to change. This is an adorable and most praiseworthy conclusion, and
>   anything that is adorable is a worshipful something. **These masters of
>   the Vedas Samhitas, therefore, recognised a divinity in all things**.
>   **There is a god behind every phenomenon, which is another way of saying
>   there is an imperishable background behind every perishable
>   phenomenon.** The sun rises in the east, the sun sets in the west;
>   clouds gather, pour rain and then go; seasons change; something comes,
>   something goes; we are born, we become old and we also go. Everything
>   is changing, everywhere, even in the vast universe of astronomical
>   calculation.

That which doesn't change (underlying reality) is called by various names such as Purusha, Brahman, Atman (which is same as Brahman as per Advaita), consciousness etc. You can read complete introduction to understand it in more detail.

What logically said by Swamiji "that which doesn't change is present in every being, every phenomenon" is present in Vedas also. For example, Sri Rudram says this ultimate reality (as Rudra) is present in everything . See [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15705/3500). Very first verse of [Isha Upanishad](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/isha-upanishad/d/doc122460.html) states:

> ईशावास्यमिदं सर्वं यत्किञ्च जगत्यां जगत् । 
>  ‘Whatever there is
>   changeful in this ephemeral world, all that must be enveloped by the
>   Lord

Book [God exists](http://www.dlshq.org/download/god_exists.htm) by [Swami Sivananda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sivananda_Saraswati) might be also useful. Swami Sivananda explains logically by answering various questions of an atheist/agnostic and also quoting direct verses from scriptures.

Comment: God does not necessarily mean Brahman. it means Bhagavan also Who respinds to calks, listens to prayers and saves from danger.Existence of God can not be proved. And Krishnanandaji's expl is true so long as one is alive. if I die with my body, there is no eternal consciousness.So atheists are never convinced:)

Comment: @ParthaBanerjee Yes. English word "God" is not Brahman. It can be used for Deva but even it is always better to use word "Deva".  Obviously, existence of God can't be proved but we can at least logically explain that Brahman exists and indeed He alone is Sat-Chid-Ananda.

Comment: Excellent answer!!

Comment: If Bhagavan exists, He or She is also Sachchidananda:) i dont want to be sugar, i like to eat sugar:)

Comment: This proves absolutely nothing and is not logic at all.

Comment: "Book God exists by Swami Sivananda might be also useful." - it begins with "Publishers' Note - Doubt in the very existence of God has been raised in the mind of the common man, by the evil-doers for fulfilling their nefarious ends. The modern atheist has his **omnipotent and omniscient scientific research laboratory**; and that whose existence cannot be proved there does not exist!" - I doubt any philosopher will take a book which begins with those lines seriously!

Comment: And in the same book he says: "Atheist want proofs for the existence of God. Can they give proof for the non-existence of God? **No one has succeeded in showing proofs that God does not exist.**" -- this is the classic argument from ignorance / [shifting the burden of proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burden_of_proof_(philosophy)#Shifting_the_burden_of_proof).

Comment: @Wikash_hindu it logically proves there is an entity which doesn't change and  says that entity is God. Swami Vivekananda also said the same IIRC.

Comment: No it does not. He says it seems that everthing is changing therefore god. First of all he did not prove that everything is changing. Secondly, who says that that change is not something else like a fairy god mother? Thirdly why has this change a super natural origin?

Comment: @Wikash_hindu Truth can only be one and constant at all times and places. Absolute entity can't change.  Are the statements like seasons, days self evident to prove there is change everywhere?

Comment: @The Destroyer. He did not prove that there is an existence of an absolute entity. Moreover, that a season changes does NOT mean that change is eveywhere. Thirdly, that everything changes does not imply the need a something that does not change. This reasoning is not logical at all.

Comment: Your statement about change in the beginning "The change doesn't know the Change" contradicts your end paragraph where one observes "Everything is changing, everywhere, even in the vast universe of astronomical calculation."  @TheDestroyer

Comment: @PrasannaR It doesn't contradict. Change doesn't know but entity which doesn't change can know change. That entity is Atman/Brahman. "Everything is changing, everywhere, even in the vast universe of astronomical calculation". We know this change because of Atman.

Answer (score 7):

No, God's existence can never be 'proved' to others. In our scriptures, this experience is called स्वसंवेद्य meaning it can be experienced only by the self.

The concept of God varies from sect to sect. Also, the words Brahman, Paramatma and Bhagavan has different meanings.

And the tranlation of proof to sanskrit could be 'Pramana'. In Indian spiriculture culture, the sayings of the Vedas and seers are accepted as Pramana. But that is not applicable to someone who is still thinking of whether to accept this tradition or not.

Also, proof or logic is related to mind and intellect while our scriptures say that God is experienced beyond mind and intellect.

So I say, the existence of God CAN NOT BE PROVED.

Comment: Did you see the God?

Comment: @PratikCJoshi Ha Ha! would i then be a writing onmsuch networks? i wd have been left everything and be absorbed in God:)

Comment: PratikCJoshi, have u seen Newton or Dinosaurs or any other historic beings. You've only read about them in books and you still believe them. Similarly, earlier people have seen Gods,they know of their stories and deeds and therefore they have described the same in books for future generations to refer. If you can't believe on Hindu scriptures as they are only written texts then there should be no reason to believe the other things also that you haven't seen physically.

Comment: @Aby how can you believe in magic God did in past? I mean is it even possible?

Comment: how can you say they were just magic & not advanced science. I believe that was advanced science like Pushpak Viman working with Voice command or Gestures or difficult surgeries like head transplant of Lord Ganesha, etc. It may be the case that they look magic to us but same is true with many scientific things of today also. I think it was either the writers who dont know detail of these sciences so they just described these things without explaining the complex procedure behind these or they wanted to write the text simply for common people to understand without going into complexities.

Comment: @Pratik C Joshi ur last mssg reached me als:) my humble suggestion is that there is no need of believing in what seems to be fairy tales. if you like the Truth, just go on seeking the truth.If Truth is there and ur seeking is intense, our saints say that it will manifest before you. btw i personally neither believe nor disbelieve the puranas as events may take place at different planes.but i stay away from these:)