# Why does god exist?

Tags: gods

If god exists, then for what reason and why does he exist? Is it that he exists only for creation and destruction? What does he get by doing so? Why doesn't he appears when someone calls to him? Is not it frustrating?

Can it be assumed that if someone doesn't appear or respond even after a deadly call to him that he doesn't exist? Does that means God doesn't exist?

Comment: Only few of the six philosophies believe in the existence of God.The God who responds to call is only mentioned in the bhakti-shastras.Either we have to believe in the sayings of such scriptures and saints and seek for ourselves or we can deny its existence outright.

Comment: Also please see the answers in https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32370/whats-the-proof-that-god-exists

Comment: I would advise you to clean up our post using proper english grammar and spelling.

Comment: People here seem to be too eager to close questions.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu You can edit any post to if you can improve it without changing content by OP

Comment: @KrishnaShweta considering his reputation score I assume he can do it himself.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu yes. But if you find any error then you can also do. It's not that only OP should edit :-)

Comment: ...why not ?...

Comment: @ram prove your statement.

Comment: 'why' can only be asked within the sensual universe. Cause and effect are only applicable within the realm of cause and effect. There is no 'why' beyond the sensual universe. who will ask whom beyond the sensual universe? There are no questions beyond the sensual universe, your question as such is not logical.

Comment: 'even after a deadly call to him' - what do you mean by this? Also, see related: [For what reasons do prayers go unanswered?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21081/for-what-reasons-do-prayers-go-unanswered)

Answer (score 0):

According to me, there is a positive source of energy, we call it 'God'.
We are growing, plants are growing. Who is responsible for that? Is there any person? Is there any scientist. No the answer is that positive source of energy 'God'.

Shri Krishna said that he had come to Earth as 'human being' so he could not use powers of 'Narayana'. If he used his powers, the war (Mahabharata) would have finished in a  day only.

This source responses by giving you confidence that he is with you. Whenever you face any trouble, you have an unknown confidence. Have you ever wonder why God is your first whenever you face any trouble, this is because he creates a new sourse in you.

You feel that if he is with you can overcome any difficult situation, it makes your mind to move ahead
This is how we can feel his existence.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE. Answers on this site should be detailed enough to solve the questioner's doubts and also should be backed up by proofs from Hindu scriptures like Vedas, Puranas, Upanishads, etc. So, please edit your answer to provide more details and proof from scriptures in order to make it more reliable.

Comment: "Who is responsible for that? " we are. Cells replicate and is part of a process called mitosis no god interferes with that process.