# God present in impurities?

Tags: gods, advaita

According to Advaita Vedanta
God is present in wood, air, and other things. It's in all the movable and immovable things
God present in evrywhere.

**Is god present in impurities like urine, semen, stool also?**

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15705/11875

Comment: Yes, brahman pervades everything just like space pervades everything. Just as space is not affected by any impurities, so also, brahman is not affected.

Comment: 'Sarvam Khalvidam Brahman'. Brahman/God is like an infinite space in Advaita Vedanta and universe with beings, a temporary projection within it. Does your TV get impure by showing stool, urine, dirt etc.,? As long there's body ego, sense-desires and no Self-realization or Atman Gyan, Advaita Vedanta should not be practiced as it can't be comprehended with intellect, rather Dvaita or Bhakti Yoga should be followed.

Comment: The things you mentioned are impurities for humans. They are not impure for many species on earth itself. Parabrahman perception is not same as either human perception or other species.

Comment: There is only Brahman. Pure and impure is a fiction within the mind.